# Windbg isn't connected to target pc

Tags: debugging, windbg, remote-debugging

I don't know where i make a mistake. I try to connect mi host pc (Windows 7) to target pc (virtual machine with Windows 7) in order to start with remote kernel debugging.

**Vmware (virtual machine) serial port settings:**

[image]

**Windgb kernel debugging:**

[image]

**Boot virtual machine settings:**

[image]

If I turn on or turn off virtual machine, nothing happens..

[image]

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? By the way, is it possible to view content of variables in a driver using LiveKd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed debug port to 2 and host machine can connect to target machine, but windbg get error message "Assertion failed: Missing StreamContext Support ..." and VM hangs at the "Starting Windows" and nothing more happens..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Those settings look correct to me.  Occasionally when I see the same behavior I just tell WinDbg to "Break" and that appears to finish the connection.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with much the same thing.  It's been a while since I've spent much time kernel debugging with Windbg.  I run Linux for pretty much everything, so this time I tried using two **KVM/QEMU** VM's managed by **Libvirt**.  Lots of different complexity there, since the version of Libvirt I'm using doesn't provide easy "ui" methods of connecting serial ports between VMs (*Libvirt hint*:  the XML setup for the serial ports, one system's Serial port source type must be set to **"bind"** and one system set to **"connect"**, even for serial type **"unix"**)

Finally, I was able to use **Putty** on both VM's and chat back and forth, confirming the COM ports I've chosen are indeed connected.
... and still Windbg on my debug host continued to say **"Waiting to connect..."**

Just confirming @jcopenha's answer, sending **Break**  did just work for me (I don't have Break on my laptop kbd, so I used the `Debug Menu` to choose "Break").

The Target system is frozen (yes, after the target was fully booted, which was another question I couldn't remember the answer to), and `!process` gives me interesting info from the target system.  I would Up-Vote their answer, but I am new to StackOverflow and don't have the reputation yet.

Thank you!